# How to fix strlen seg fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, strlen

I am trying to get the string length of my key for my hash function, and I keep receiving this error in GDB at my the place where I try to use strlen:

```
"_strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S:79
79  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S: No such file or directory."
```

I've tried running gdb, I am not allowed to use the string class, I know my program doesn't get past this line of code.

```
int table::hashfunc(char key[])
{       
     int hash = 0;
      int k = 1;      
     int key_size = strlen(key); //PROGRAM DOESN'T RUN PAST HERE

      for(int i = 0; i < key_size; ++i)
      {       
              hash = hash + (int)key[i];
              hash = pow(hash, k);
      }
      int index = hash % SIZE;
      return index;


 }

 //This is where I call the hash function from.

int table::add_name(char character[], char movie[], char choice)
{ 
    int index = hashfunc(character);
```

I expected the key_size to be set to the number of characters in the key, but when I check the strlen(key) in gdb I get this:

```
 (gdb) print strlen(key)
 $1 = (size_t (*)(const char *)) 0x7ffff7156620 <__strlen_sse2>
```

here is where I'm reading in the char key:

```
do  
     {
    cout << "Please enter the name of the film you 
would like to add to: " <<endl;
                            cin.get(temp_movie, temp_size);
                            cin.ignore(100, '\n');

                            cout << "Enter 'C' to add a character, 
enter 'A' to add an actor: " <<endl;
                            cin >> choice;
                            cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                            choice = toupper(choice);

                            cout << "Enter the name of the character or 
 actor you would like to add: " <<endl;
                            cin.get(temp_name, temp_size);
                            cin.ignore(100, '\n');

                            if(choice == 'C')    
                                    character_table.add_name(temp_name, 
 temp_movie, choice);
                            else if(choice == 'A')
                                    actor_table.add_name(temp_name, 
  temp_movie, choice);
                            else
                                    cout << "That is an invalid choice. 
 please try again." <<endl;


                    }while(choice != 'A' && choice != 'C');
```

Answer (score 2):

The `strlen` [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) says this:

> Returns the length of the given byte string, that is, the number of
>   characters in a character array whose first element is pointed to by
>   str up to and not including the first null character. The behavior is
>   undefined if there is no null character in the character array pointed
>   to by str.

Probably your `char key[]` is missing an ending null char `\0`.

Comment: Doesn't cin.get automatically add the terminating null? 
I also had it reading in as cin.get(temp_name, temp_size, '\0') and it was doing the same thing.  And thank you!!

Comment: `cin.get` doesn't add '\0'. `cin.get(temp_name, temp_size, '\0')` reads chars from `temp_name` until it has read `temp_size` number of chars or finds `\0`.